# Error connecting to an SSH server through a proxy in Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to connect to a remote SSH server through a proxy using paramiko, but its failing with "Error reading SSH banner"

I tried connecting using ssh command from the terminal and it worked fine, i also tried connecting to the proxy instead of the final destination it also worked fine. However, when i try connecting to the final destination through the proxy its raising a timeout and displaying the error mentioned above, i tried increasing the timeout value but that didn't seem to solve it, it would run till the specified timeout value and then throw the error.
I'm suspecting that it could be something in the configuration on my machine that paramiko is looking for but not finding hence the timeout, because other than that i'm connecting with no issues from terminal.

Comment: please post a [repro].

Comment: And log files both from Paramiko and `ssh` (from the same machine).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.